# Types defined in src/main.rs are not recognized in tests/test.rs file

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust

I tried to write a unit test in rust, but when I run cargo test I get the following error:
"use of undeclared type Rating".
In the src/main.rs file I have defined the struct Rating like this:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Rating(i8);

impl Rating {
    pub fn new(value: i32) -> Result <Rating, CreationError> {
        match value {
            v if v > 10 => Err(CreationError::PosOverflow),
            v if v < -10 => Err(CreationError::NegOverflow),
            _ => Ok(Rating(value as i8)),
        }

    }
}
```

My test file tests/test.rs looks like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
fn create_new_rating() {
    assert_eq!(Rating::new(10).0, 10);
}
```

In the Rust documentation I only found examples where libs are tested but not binarys. Do I have to use a different syntax in this case?

Comment: Integration tests are testing the library, not the binary. That is, they refer to `lib.rs`, not `main.rs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `tests` folder is for integration tests, and needs to use your crate as though it were an external user. Add `use mycratename::Rating` to the top of the test.rs, and make Rating public.

If this is a unit test (which this looks like), it is idiomatic to put tests in the same file as the code. This is described in [the Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html). You would end up with something like:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Rating(i8);

impl Rating {
    pub fn new(value: i32) -> Result <Rating, CreationError> {
        match value {
            v if v > 10 => Err(CreationError::PosOverflow),
            v if v < -10 => Err(CreationError::NegOverflow),
            _ => Ok(Rating(value as i8)),
        }

    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn create_new_rating() {
        assert_eq!(Rating::new(10).0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! the unit test way works. I also tried use mycratename::Rating; and made Rating pub but I still get the same error. mycratename is the parentfolder of src and tests respectively the name field in my Cargo.toml file right?

Comment: Yes, mycratename should be replaced with what you mentioned. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. If you scroll down a bit to [integration tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests) in the linked chapter of the Rust Book, you'll see the actual requirements with an example you can compare to.